# How can I improve query performance based off explain/indexing

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, innodb

```
SELECT journey.code
FROM journey
JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.code
JOIN pattern ON pattern.code = journey.pattern
JOIN link ON link.section = pattern.section
WHERE journey_day.day = 5 AND TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN journey.departure AND journey.end
GROUP BY journey.code
```

The query above takes 500ms-1s on average. Here's a screenshot of an explain: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD8IY.png

I can't figure out why it's taking this long, I'm trying to optimize the query so it executes <= 100ms.

Sadly it seems SQL Fiddle is currently having technical issues with building schematics/viewing Fiddles, so I'll instead try and describe the index set up below:

INDEX:

- journey.pattern
- journey.departure
- journey.end
- pattern.code
- pattern.section
- link.section

UNIQUE:

- journey.code
- journey_day.journey **+** journey_day.day

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Your query is retrieving one column from the `journey` table.  The `where` conditions and `group by` are only on that table and `journey_day`.  What are the other tables being used for?

Comment: @GordonLinoff In my production query I am selecting more than this but it had no effect on query speed when I tested so I left it out of the question to keep things simple

Answer (score 0):

A few items to mention....  You appear to have indexes on individual columns instead of a compound single index of multiple fields, most specifically to the journey table.  I would suggest the following indexes as below

```
journey  (departure, end, code, pattern )
journey_day ( journey, day )
pattern (code)
link (section)
```

Secondly, you are only grabbing the code from the journey table, but are not really doing anything from the pattern or link table, so I don't know why you including them in your query and could be reduced to

```
SELECT DISTINCT j.code 
   FROM journey j 
   JOIN journey_day jd 
        ON j.code = jd.journey 
        AND jd.day = 5 
   WHERE 
      TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN j.departure AND j.end
```